# How can I maximize a specific window through cmd? (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, maximize-window

I just want to make a simple [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) .bat file that would maximize a specific process window. Is that possible?

Answer (score 20):

If you want to maximize an already-running program/window you can try with [***windowMode.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat) using its title (or a string that the title starts with):

```
@echo off
call windowMode -title "Notepad" -mode maximized
```

Or with its process id:

```
@echo off
call windowMode -pid 1313 -mode maximized
```

Comment: Thanks for this, saves the day when IntelliJ stays in a minimized state with no way to get it to behave like it should. Cool idea to have a batch with code and invoking csc on it to do advanced magic.

Comment: This should have been the answer as the OP asked about maximizing any process

Answer (score 13):

**[`Start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)** takes an argument to do that.

```
START /MAX notepad.exe
```

However, if it is an already-running instance, it is outside of **cmd**'s control.

Comment: Nice! I needed a BAT script to start a process (a shell) in a maximized CMD. This did the trick: `START /MAX cmd.exe /C "mode con cols=500 lines=500 && bin/my_shell.exe"`