# How to maximize already minimized file(java)?

Tags: java, batch-file

In my application i need my Excel file to get maximize whether in the foreground or background.I have using batch file command "START "file_window_title" /MAX" But it maximizes the Command prompt window but not the file whose title is mentioned in the command?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760518/how-can-i-maximize-a-specific-window-through-cmdwindows

Answer (score 0):

This is a hybrid batch/javascript file (save as `.cmd`) that will try to maximize a window given its title. You can call it as

```
maximize.cmd "This is the window title"
```

If a window exists that match this title, `sendkeys` method is used to send <kbd>Alt+space</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to use the window menu to maximize it.

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    rem call javascript part of batch file
    cscript //nologo //e:Javascript "%~f0" /title:"%~1"

    rem End of batch area. Ensure batch ends execution before reaching
    rem javascript zone
    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************

    // Instantiate shell component
    var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');

    // Activate window
    if (shell.AppActivate(WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('title'))){
        // Maximize window
        shell.SendKeys('% x');
    };

    // Exit
    WScript.Quit();
```